# How to call a PHP function in an URL of ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have written a PHP code having single function with an **echo** statement and I wish to call that function as a **url** in **ajax** code.
I tired doing this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Writing PHP Function</title>

        <script>

        $.ajax(
        {
        url : localhost/practice.php/f=myFirst();
        type: "GET",
        data: dataString,

        success: function(result)
        {
        alert(result);
        }
        });

        </script>

    </head>
<body>

        <?php

            function myFirst()
            { 
             echo 'The First ran successfully.'; 
            }

        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you call that function ...it will append `The First ran successfully` which makes no sense

Comment: you need to elaborate further. Provide the php code and tell us what the exact issue is.

Comment: 1. You would need to change your url to `localhost/practice.php/?f=myFirst` and 2. You would need to return your value, not print it. 3. You should map the request to the functions

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong with what you have. Here is just a simple example that should work for you.

**practice.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['f']))
        echo strip_tags($_GET['f']);
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php function myFirst() {
    echo 'The First ran successfully.';
} ?><html>
<head>
<title>Writing PHP Function</title>
<!-- You need to add the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// You should activate it on an event like click (unless you want it to autoload)
$("#content").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            // Your url is funky, and cannot be terminated with a semicolon
            // but rather a comma
            url : 'localhost/practice.php?f=<?php myFirst(); ?>',
            type: "GET",
            // You can do an alert, but I just made it populate a div instead
            success: function(result) {
                $("#place-to-load").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
    </head>
<body>
<!-- Your php function will not work as you intend because one -->
<!-- is a server-side function and the other is a client-side script -->
<!-- The functions are not interchangeable. That being said, you can -->
<!-- populate a javascript with a php variable but it would need to be -->
<!-- echoed like <?php myFirst(); ?> -->
<div id="place-to-load"></div>
<div id="content">Load</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir thanks this one is working..
But what my main agenda is to have a PHP file having multiple functions like insert, retrieve from database.
and i am suppose to make call to one specific function using Ajax on button click of insert and show on my page .

Comment: You put all those functions on your `practice.php` page.

Comment: All your working php script is on the `practice.php` page. All the `index.php` page does is activate those scripts/functions and call them into a container on the `index.php` page

Answer (score 0):

I would try to call the functions based on the params from the URL.
Ajax part,

```
$.ajax({url:'localhost/practice.php?f=myFirst',type:'GET'}).done(function(response){
  alert(response); // or you can write to your document
});
```

and PHP file

```
<?php
      if(isset($_GET) && $_GET['f'] == 'myFirst'){
        myFirst();
      }else{
        die('No GET params received');
      }

      function myFirst(){ 
           echo 'The First ran successfully.'; 
      }

?>
```